# Debug Go Web service project with VSC

Tags: google-chrome, go, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have a web service program by golang.
This program is working well by command "go run main.go", launching chrome(web browser).
I`d like to debug this project with VSC.
So I wrote configurations in .vsccode\launch.json as following:

```
    {
        "name": "GOWEB_DEBUG",
        "type": "go",
        "request": "launch",
        "mode": "debug",
        "buildFlags": "-tags='ptr64'",
        "program": "/root/gowebserver",
    },
```

Then, follwing error message box is appeared and can`t debug.
**Failed to launch: could not launch process: not an executable files.**
Above configuration infos are working well on go application project.

And main() function is like this:

func main() {

```
http.HandleFunc("/playground/examples", playground.GetExampleFileList)
...........

fmt.Println("Starting web service for playground on http://127.0.0.1:5336/")

http.ListenAndServe(":5336", nil) //here, web browser is executed.
```

}

Comment: Is `"program": "/root/gowebserver"` the package directory? The DEBUG CONSOLE should have error message if it was due to build error.

Comment: Thank you!
Are you korean?